# Make a call on click but with confirmation

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to click on a TextView and make a call to a telephone number but not directly, with the confirmation of the user. My code is this but it makes the call directly when I click

```
txt_ocho.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txt_ocho.getText().toString().trim()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
            Log.d("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed" + activityException);
        }
    }
});
```

Can Somebody help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your onClick block, display an `alertDialog` with 2 buttons (cancel and confirm).

```
txt_ocho.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("Confirm call")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to make the phone call?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            try {
                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + txt_ocho.getText().toString().trim()));
                 startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                 Log.d("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed" + activityException);
            }   
        }

    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
    .show();
 }    
});
```

Comment: Well you need user interaction. Here `alertDialog` seems a correct solution to me.

Comment: Perhaps it would be the possibility to open the call screen but not call until the user press the call button

Comment: Yep, depends what you want, stay in app or not !

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Also, in your xml file, you could add those attribute to the textview : android:autoLink="phone" android:linksClickable="true"

Answer (score 1):

```
final ArrayList<String> getContacts = new ArrayList<>();
```

add your phone numbers to this ArrayList
like this:

```
getContacts.add(125486842);
getContacts.add(48686223174);

txt_ocho.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            int numOfContacts = getContacts.size();
                            builder.setItems(getContacts.toArray(new String[numOfContacts]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    // for bring up dial screen with phone number filled
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getContacts.get(which)));
                                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            })
                                    .setTitle("set a title")
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                }

            });
```

Comment: I don´t understand this code, how can I use in my example? thanks

Comment: @AnderEnzunza i changed that

Answer (score 1):

On click on the textview, you can directly bring the user to the phone call screen adding those attributes to your `TextView` (xml file) :

```
android:autoLink="phone" 
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Then you don't need to handle intent in your code ! :)